# dyld: Library not loaded when building to real device on iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, dyld, rpath

[image]

That happens when I try to build my app to a real iOS device. I'm using a Cocoa Touch Framework (introduced in the iOS 8 SDK). On the iOS Simulator works fine.

Comment: This is happening during the build or when running the app?

Comment: OK, so what is the app *run path* set to and have you included the `.dylib` in the app bundle?

Comment: On the framework target I have this on the Runpath search path: @executable_path/Frameworks @loader_path/Frameworks // On the app target, i have: @loader_path/../Library/Frameworks

Comment: That needs to be on the app target, and is the `.dylib` part of the app bundle?

Comment: Which .dylib? I created the framework as a new target but it didn't generate any .dylib

Comment: OK the framework then; is it being copied into the app bundle and does the *run path* of the app include its path?

Comment: On the Runpath search path on the app target I have this: @rpath/AluanaKit.framework/AluanaKit so I suppose yes, it does includes its path

Comment: You cannot have `@rpath` in the run path as that makes no sense.  Use `@loader_path` or `@executable_path`.

Comment: OK, I've tried adding @loader_path/../AluanaKit.framework/AluanaKit but it keeps crashing

Comment: Where is the app *relative* to `AluanaKit.framework` in the app bundle?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what do you mean, but I guess it's a folder called AluanaKit, inside my project. I can't see any AluanaKit.framework, so I suppose it's compiled at runtime

Comment: No. Look at the app bundle and figure out where the framework is relative to the app and this will help you configure the *run path*.

Comment: Do you mean looking into the .app?

Comment: Yes; you need to know the bundle structure in order to configure the *run path*

Comment: Where can I find the bundle?

Comment: In `DerivedData`; look at the details in the build log which should tell you exactly where.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XlAOPMv.png This is what I found in there, but there's no framework inside the .app. So what should I put in order to configure the run path?

Answer (score 0):

Is your device also iOS8? It has to be the same version as your SDK or it doesn't carry the library you will be using.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the iOS 8 b4 SDK and the device has iOS 8 b4, so yes, it's the same version.